# How much does it cost to train an astronaut?

Tags: astronauts, cost

What are the total costs to train an astronaut from selection until they are ready to go to space? How much time does it take? And is it possible to break down the costs by category (salary, training, medical etc.)?

The specific example I am interested in is Alexander Gerst.

How much did it cost to train Alexander Gerst from the moment of the congratulatory handshake when he was selected into the ESA Astronaut programme to the moment he boarded the Soyuz capsule for the ISS the first time?

If you know about a similar example (NASA, ESA, Роскосмос etc.), that would be fine too.

Comment: Sefe, since you mentioned ESA, are you interested in the cost of ESA's 16-month [basic training](https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/Astronauts/Basic_training)? Or were you looking for something more?

Comment: @called2voyage: I am interested in how much it costs to train an astronaut. I thought this is a simple question that should be easy to answer, since [other similar questions](https://www.quora.com/How-much-does-it-cost-to-train-a-fighter-pilot-in-different-air-forces-throughout-the-world) seem to be answerable at other places. Alas, this does not seem to be the case here. As for your specific comment. Was the 16 month basic training enough to make Alex ready for the ISS? Then, yes the basic training. If not then - as the question specifically mentions - the entire cost until then.

Comment: Where do you draw the line for startup and overhead costs? (e.g. paying the costs of construction of training facilities, support staff, etc...)

Comment: "I thought this is a simple question that should be easy to answer" It is clear that you have little experience with government budgeting and accounting :)

Comment: I don't think an itemised list down to the last cent is needed. An order of magnitude estimation would probably suffice. $500,000? $10,000,000? $100,000,000?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Isn‘t that the point of a Q&A? You ask something you don‘t know about, someone answers and then you do? Some expert *could* just pick an example he knows about and write about it. Maybe you need to be a rocket scientist to not find it bizarre that so far the only reaction is a debate whether this is a good question.

Comment: The problem is that there is no good way to answer it. How do you account for the facility cost? For example, do you take the total cost of the ISS  training simulator and divide it by the total number of astronauts who have been trained in it? How about the salaries of all the instructors? The cost of running the 50 year old T-38s they fly in? What salary does the guy make? Does ESA pay his living expenses when he's in the US training? Could you divide the ESA training budget for a year by the number of crew? How about the training they get in Russia? Good luck with that one.

Comment: To be clear: I don't object to the question in its current form, I voted to reopen.  I just found your comment "I thought this is a simple question that should be easy to answer" amusing.

Comment: Yes, @Organic Marble, I think this (How much does it cost to train an astronaut?) is a question with as good way to give an answer as the question about O/F ratio in SuperDraco engines. About as specific and with about as much information available.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Economics has centuries of experience of breaking down fixed costs. Any company that is bigger than a couple of people can do (and has to do) cash flow calculations. How do you calculate the price of a built-for-purpose product if there is no way to do that? If you would start outsourcing the astronaut training you would face exactly this issue since your service provider would want to make a profit (even a not-for-profit company wouldn't want to make losses).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-much-does-it-cost-to-train-an-astronaut):

> Figures quoted by the BBC yesterday, as they showed UK astronaut Tim Peake reaching the International Space Station, suggested £16M and 6 years of training.  There may be an improvement in the economics if a nation sponsors multiple astronauts.

I think for Alex Gerst it would be a similar quote, but remember that Mathias Maurerer is also a German Astronaut who graduated from Basic Training.

Later edit:

Today at the saturation diving classes at university I heard from one of our professors that training astronaut cost 15 million USD. This is very close to the previous estimates and seems to confirm it.

Comment: Nice find! Welcome to space stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had seen this link before but this is quoting another quote without a source. I was hoping for a first hand account by someone who is in the business of training astronauts.